# Spring actuator: /configprops not showing HikariCP datasource

Tags: spring-boot, hikaricp, spring-boot-actuator

I've switched recently to HikariCP instead of tomcat connection pool.
I was checking connection properties via `/configprops` actuator endpoint, but now what I'm getting is this:

```
"dataSource" : {
 "prefix" : "spring.datasource.hikari",
 "properties" : {
  "error" : "Cannot serialize 'spring.datasource.hikari'"
 }
}
```

How can I make it return normal values? I've thought spring boot should handle this with `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.metadata.HikariDataSourcePoolMetadata`

Answer (score 1):

So what I've found that Hikari's `DriverDataSource` threw `SQLFeatureNotSupportedException` on some getters. Only way to overcome this problem is to customize actuator page. Luckily it happens to be relatively easy:

```
@Component
public class MyConfigurationPropertiesReportEndpoint extends ConfigurationPropertiesReportEndpoint {

  @Override
  protected void configureObjectMapper(ObjectMapper mapper) {
    super.configureObjectMapper(mapper);
    mapper.addMixIn(HikariDataSource.class, HikariDataSourceMixIn.class);
  }
}
```

And MixIn:

```
public abstract class HikariDataSourceMixIn {

  @JsonIgnore
  abstract PrintWriter getLogWriter();

  @JsonIgnore
  abstract HikariConfigMXBean getHikariConfigMXBean();
}
```